# Short explanation on Database Types

Tags: database

I'm deciding what database to use for my project, but I've only ever used relational databases (Oracle, MySQL) so for my web project I figured I'd use MySQL with PHPMyAdmin for DBMS.

But **I'd like to know more about other database types, succinctly if possible**, before I finally decide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you loves to do many own projects and practices then i should prefer MySQL..But if you are saying that you wants to go to better MNC companies as well then go to ORACLE..Becoz MySQL is free of cost and easily learnable by ourself..But ORACLE is like professional with more diificult learning curves ..ORACLE better for your reliable carrier...